# How To CaptureScreen at Virtual Desktop?

Tags: winapi, hwnd, virtual-desktop

I run test program windows8 or 7 64/32bit

but i can't capture screen when running virtual desktop

here is my code

```
hwnd h1 = createwindows(....) or dialog.. //if this line remove capture code works fine

hDesktopCurrent = NULL;
hOriginalInput = NULL;
hDesktopCurrent = GetThreadDesktop(GetCurrentThreadId());
hOriginalInput = OpenInputDesktop(0, FALSE, DESKTOP_SWITCHDESKTOP);

hDeskVirtual= NULL;

attr.nLength = sizeof(attr);
attr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
attr.bInheritHandle = true;

hDeskVirtual= CreateDesktopEx(
    "my_new_desktop_1",
    NULL,
    NULL,
    0,
    GENERIC_ALL,
    &attr,
    0,
    NULL);

SwitchDesktop(hDeskVirtual);
SetThreadDesktop(hDeskVirtual);

//capture here

SwitchDesktop(originaldesktop);
SetThreadDesktop(originaldesktop);
```

ps:
When I nerver create any windows hwnd before switchdesktop
(ex:createwindows,creatdialog...) it works perfertly capture..

but I create any windows frame or dialog,
it didn't work 
that only captured BlackScreen

plz..help me!

Comment: [The `SetThreadDesktop` function will fail if the calling thread has any windows or hooks on its current desktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686250%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).